# Installing multiple versions of Aptana?

Tags: aptana

I want to upgrade to Aptana 3, but on first glance there were a few things different I didn't have time to spend figuring them all out. So I went back to 2. I'd like to install 3 as well so when I have time I can just look at it. I use Aptana too much and rarely have a lot of time to spending figuring out all their changes but there are some benefits to upgrading.

So is there a way I can hide my Aptana 2 from the install wizard for 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not *quite* what you asked for, I would install the 3.x version as a plugin into Eclipse. Realistically, you should be able to install 2.x and 3.x side-by-side, so the fact you can't sounds like a bug, and I would recommend filing a bug ticket for that.

Comment: I know this is super old, but my account had some kind of recursive glitch that just now got fixed. I don't know why I didn't notice that both can be installed side by side but regardless, I've been using 3 for awhile and love it. Thanks for answering though.